# How to Take input of "Ctrl s" or "Ctrl 1" in PERL

Tags: perl, perl-module

Actually I am trying to take input from user until he presses <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>END</kbd> or <kbd>F7</kbd> {keyboard buttons}

How can I let my perl code know about this, whenever user presses above specified buttons or combination of those buttons?

Comment: [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::ReadKey)

Comment: WOW.. Can you please answer this question, i am not able to do so, i got this link as reference -> http://doc.sumy.ua/prog/pb/cookbook/ch15_07.htm , thanks bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    use strict;

    use Term::ReadKey;
    ReadMode 4;
    my $key = ReadKey(0);
    print "Get key ", ord($key), "\n";

    ReadMode 0; # Reset tty mode before exiting
```

Comment: Does that handle modifier keys (e.g. control)?

Comment: It looks like it supports ctrl+d and similar.